# Is there a function in python to split a word into a list?

Tags: python, function, split

Is there a function in python to split a word into a list of single letters? e.g:

```
s = "Word to Split"
```

to get

```
wordlist = ['W', 'o', 'r', 'd', ' ', 't', 'o', ' ', 'S', 'p', 'l', 'i', 't']
```

Comment: just check out this documentation: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html

Comment: Old thread, but it's worth mentioning: Most of the time you don't need to do this at all.  The characters of a python string can be accessed as a list directly ie. `s[2]` is 'r', and `s[:4]` is 'Word' and `len(s)` is 13.  You can iterate over them as well: `for char in s: print char`

Comment: @domoarrigato  but due to different behavior of srting and list for mutability  can be reason to do this.

Comment: def show_letters(word):
 for ch in word:
  print(ch)

show_letters("Hello")

Answer (score 263, accepted):

```
>>> list("Word to Split")
['W', 'o', 'r', 'd', ' ', 't', 'o', ' ', 'S', 'p', 'l', 'i', 't']
```

Comment: Any reason you know of why "Word to Split".split('') doesn't do the same thing. It doesn't, but really seems like it should.

Comment: @Walter Nissen: I get "ValueError: empty separator" when trying that. The empty regex is not terribly well defined.

Comment: Is there no delimiter for using `split()` to get the characters? `split()` takes a second argument *maxsplits*, but there is no equivalent with `list()`. Of course there are work arounds...

Answer (score 29):

The easiest way is probably just to use `list()`, but there is at least one other option as well:

```
s = "Word to Split"
wordlist = list(s)               # option 1, 
wordlist = [ch for ch in s]      # option 2, list comprehension.
```

They should *both* give you what you need:

```
['W','o','r','d',' ','t','o',' ','S','p','l','i','t']
```

As stated, the first is likely the most preferable for your example but there are use cases that may make the latter quite handy for more complex stuff, such as if you want to apply some arbitrary function to the items, such as with:

```
[doSomethingWith(ch) for ch in s]
```

Answer (score 11):

The list function will do this

```
>>> list('foo')
['f', 'o', 'o']
```

Answer (score 4):

Abuse of the rules, same result:
    (x for x in 'Word to split')

Actually an iterator, not a list. But it's likely you won't really care.

Comment: Of course, `'Word to split'` used directly is also an iterable of its own characters, so the generator expression is just pointless wrapping.

Answer (score 2):

```
text = "just trying out"

word_list = []

for i in range(len(text)):
    word_list.append(text[i])

print(word_list)
```

Output:

```
['j', 'u', 's', 't', ' ', 't', 'r', 'y', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' ', 'o', 'u', 't']
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest option is to just use the list() command. However, if you don't want to use it or it dose not work for some bazaar reason, you can always use this method.

```
word = 'foo'
splitWord = []

for letter in word:
    splitWord.append(letter)

print(splitWord) #prints ['f', 'o', 'o']
```

Answer (score 0):

def count():
    list = 'oixfjhibokxnjfklmhjpxesriktglanwekgfvnk'

```
word_list = []
# dict = {}
for i in range(len(list)):
    word_list.append(list[i])
# word_list1 = sorted(word_list)
for i in range(len(word_list) - 1, 0, -1):
    for j in range(i):
        if word_list[j] > word_list[j + 1]:
            temp = word_list[j]
            word_list[j] = word_list[j + 1]
            word_list[j + 1] = temp
print("final count of arrival of each letter is : \n", dict(map(lambda x: (x, word_list.count(x)), word_list)))
```