# how to convert a list of strings into a list of sublists of the individual characters in the strings?

Tags: python, list, append, sublist

So I am starting with:

```
['BLUE', 'ORANGE', 'YELLOW', 'GREEN', 'BLACK', 'PURPLE', 'BROWN']
```

and I want:

```
[['B', 'L', 'U', 'E'], ['O', 'R', 'A', 'N', 'G', 'E'], ['Y', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O', 'W'], ['G', 'R', 'E', 'E', 'N'], ['B','L', 'A', 'C', 'K'], ['P', 'U', 'R', 'P', 'L', 'E'], ['B', 'R', 'O', 'W','N']]
```

I tried this because it looked like it would produce what I wanted but it keeps telling me I have an error. AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append':

```
first_list = ['BLUE', 'ORANGE', 'YELLOW', 'GREEN', 'BLACK', 'PURPLE', 'BROWN']
list_1 = []

for i in range (len(first_list)):
    list_1 = list_1.append(list(first_list[i]))

return list_1
```

I keep having trouble using the ".append" and keep using "+" in other iterations but that just gives me a long list of all the characters instead of a list of sublists of characters. Thank you for any help or advice.

Comment: related if not duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113655/is-there-a-function-in-python-to-split-a-word-into-a-list

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The built-in [`list()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) function creates a list from an iterable object. Since a string is an iterable object, we can pass it to `list()` to create a list of the individual characters. To do this for each of the words, we can use a [list comprehension](http://carlgroner.me/Python/2011/11/09/An-Introduction-to-List-Comprehensions-in-Python.html):

```
>>> words = ['BLUE', 'ORANGE', 'YELLOW', 'GREEN', 'BLACK', 'PURPLE', 'BROWN']
>>> [list(word) for word in words]
[['B', 'L', 'U', 'E'], ['O', 'R', 'A', 'N', 'G', 'E'], ['Y', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O', 'W'], ['G', 'R', 'E', 'E', 'N'], ['B', 'L', 'A', 'C', 'K'], ['P', 'U', 'R', 'P', 'L', 'E'], ['B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N']]
```

Edit: the attribute error you were getting is because the `append()` method of a list returns None. Since you assign the output of the method to the `list1` variable, you overwrite the list with None on the first time around the loop. Since None does not have a `append` method, on the next time around the loop you get the error. Removing this assignment makes your code work:

```
>>> first_list = ['BLUE', 'ORANGE', 'YELLOW', 'GREEN', 'BLACK', 'PURPLE', 'BROWN']
>>> list_1 = []
>>> for i in range (len(first_list)):
...     list_1.append(list(first_list[i]))
... 
>>> list_1
[['B', 'L', 'U', 'E'], ['O', 'R', 'A', 'N', 'G', 'E'], ['Y', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O', 'W'], ['G', 'R', 'E', 'E', 'N'], ['B', 'L', 'A', 'C', 'K'], ['P', 'U', 'R', 'P', 'L', 'E'], ['B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N']]
```

Comment: It's an `AttributeError`, not a `SyntaxError`. (Still +1 for being not only the first recommendation for a list comprehension, but the only one that explained why to use one and gave a link.)

Comment: Thank you for explaining what my error was. Thank you everyone for all your help.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> map(list,first_list)
[['B', 'L', 'U', 'E'], ['O', 'R', 'A', 'N', 'G', 'E'], ['Y', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O', 'W'], ['G', 'R', 'E', 'E', 'N'], ['B', 'L', 'A', 'C', 'K'], ['P', 'U', 'R', 'P', 'L', 'E'], ['B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N']]
```

The `list` constructor is applied to each element of the original list. And the elements of the original list are strings, which are iterables. So `list` just consumes the string treating it as iterator, so eventually it contains the letters (as strings yields letters as elements if it's being iterated over).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply coerce a string into a list to get a list of the string's characters.

```
words = ['BLUE', 'ORANGE', 'YELLOW', 'GREEN', 'BLACK', 'PURPLE', 'BROWN']
split_words = [list(word) for word in li]
```

Comment: Judging by what he tried, he wasn't having any problem with the `list(word)` part, but with putting all the results together (the trivial list comprehension).

Answer (score 1):

The only reason your existing code doesn't work is that `list.append` modifies a list in place, and returns `None`. So:

```
for i in range (len(first_list)):
    list_1 = list_1.append(list(first_list[i]))
```

The first time through, you're adding the first word onto list_1, and then setting list_1 to `None`. So the next time through, you get an `AttributeError`.

Just do this:

```
for i in range (len(first_list)):
    list_1.append(list(first_list[i]))
```

Or use a function that doesn't modify the list in-place, but instead returns a new one:

```
for i in range (len(first_list)):
    list_1 = list_1 + [list(first_list[i])]
```

It's a bit silly to loop over `range(len(first_list))` if all you want with the index `i` is `first_list[i]`; you can just loop over `first_list` directly. (And even if you *do* need `i` for other purposes, you can loop over `enumerate(first_list)`.)

However, as many people have pointed out, it's almost always better to use a list comprehension than to try to build the list with an explicit loop.

In fact, one of the many reasons for that is that you don't have to remember `append` vs. `extend`, which functions mutate and which return new values, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
myList = ['BLUE', 'ORANGE', 'YELLOW', 'GREEN', 'BLACK', 'PURPLE', 'BROWN']

res = [[i for i in s] for s in myList]

res
[['B', 'L', 'U', 'E'], ['O', 'R', 'A', 'N', 'G', 'E'], ['Y', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O', 'W'],    ['G', 'R', 'E', 'E', 'N'], ['B', 'L', 'A', 'C', 'K'], ['P', 'U', 'R', 'P', 'L', 'E'], ['B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `list()` to each item using `map`:

```
>>> words = ['BLUE', 'ORANGE', 'YELLOW', 'GREEN', 'BLACK', 'PURPLE', 'BROWN']
>>> map(list, words)
[['B', 'L', 'U', 'E'], ['O', 'R', 'A', 'N', 'G', 'E'], ['Y', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O', 'W'], ['G', 'R', 'E', 'E', 'N'], ['B', 'L', 'A', 'C', 'K'], ['P', 'U', 'R', 'P', 'L', 'E'], ['B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N']]
```

Although I'm not sure why you'd need to do this. Strings and lists behave almost identically.

Answer (score 0):

Your current solution doesn't work because `list.append()` returns `None`, and you are assigning the result of `list_1.append()` back to `list_1`, so on the second iteration you get the attribute error.

Here is how you could fix your current code:

```
first_list = ['BLUE', 'ORANGE', 'YELLOW', 'GREEN', 'BLACK', 'PURPLE', 'BROWN']
list_1 = []
for i in range(len(first_list)):
    list_1.append(list(first_list[i]))
```

A better solution would be to loop over the items in the list directly:

```
for s in first_list:
    list_1.append(list(s))
```

But the best way to do this is to use a list comprehension or map, as in the other answers.