# Python Variable Character Split

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, variables

I am using python (version 2.7) and I have a variable called characters ('abc123'). I would like to be able to split it so that I have a list of the characters in the variable (['a', 'b', 'c', '1', '2', '3']). Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113655/is-there-a-function-in-python-to-split-a-word-into-a-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = 'abc123'

>>> list(s)
['a', 'b', 'c', '1', '2', '3']
```