# How can i Modify the given code so that the ﬁnal list only contains a single copy of each letter?

Tags: python

This is the code:

```
word_list = ['cat','dog','rabbit']
letter_list = [ ]
fora_wordinword_list:`
   fora_letterina_word:
     letter_list.append(a_letter)
print(letter_list)
```

I will Modify the given code so that the ﬁnal list only contains a single copy of each letter.

```
['c','a','t','d','o','g','r','b','i']
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a function in python to split a word into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113655/is-there-a-function-in-python-to-split-a-word-into-a-list) What you would need is to apply the function iterating the array. Does it help you?

Comment: OP doesn't want duplicates.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Python [set](https://docs.python.org/library/sets.html) is what you need. Try this:

```
word_list = ["cat", "dog", "rabbit"]
print(list(set("".join(word_list))))
```

Output:

```
['g', 'r', 'd', 'o', 'i', 'c', 't', 'b', 'a']
```

**Warning:**

[sets](https://docs.python.org/library/sets.html) DO NOT preserve the original order of the list.

> A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects. Common uses include membership testing, removing duplicates from a sequence, and computing mathematical operations such as intersection, union, difference, and symmetric difference.

However, if you are really interested in maintaining the order:

```
word_list = ["cat", "dog", "rabbit"]
result = []
for i in "".join(word_list):
    if i not in result:
        result.append(i)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['c', 'a', 't', 'd', 'o', 'g', 'r', 'b', 'i']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `chain.from_iterable` from `itertools`:

```
list(dict.fromkeys(chain.from_iterable(word_list)))
```

This on python version 3.7+ will maintain order of elements also.

Answer (score 1):

hope this will help

```
  word_list=["cat","dog","rabbit"]
   print(list(set("".join(word_list))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Better to use a set then, to adjust your previous code to do just that:

```py
word_list = ['cat','dog','rabbit']
letter_list = set()
for a_word in word_list:
    for a_letter in a_word:
        letter_list.add(a_letter)
print(list(letter_list))
```

You can also be clever with a one liner:

```
print(list(set("".join(word_list))))
```

And if you want to preserve order *without importing anything* just:

```
print(list({k: 1 for k in "".join(word_list)}))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final_output = []
for word in word_list:
    for i in range( len(word) ):
        final_output.append(sampleStr[i])
```

Try this :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the condition:

```
word_list = ['cat','dog','rabbit']
letter_list = [ ]
for word in word_list:`
   for character in word:
     if character not in letter_list:
       letter_list.append(character)
print(letter_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

In python `set` is not `ordered`. If you really care about the order, Then you can try something like this

```
word_list = ['cat','dog','rabbit']
letter_list = []

for i in "".join(word_list):
    if i not in letter_list:
        letter_list.append(i)

>>> letter_list
['c','a','t','d','o','g','r','b','i']
```