# Transform a python file into a list of letters

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, file, arraylist

I'm trying to turn a file into a list in Python that takes as elements each letters. The file 'file_input.txt' should look like this:

It
is
great

and the function should return:
['i','t','i','s','g','r','e','a','t']

I tried to do this:

```
file1 = open('file_input.txt', "r")
list_of_lists = []
for l in a_file1:
    s_line = l.strip() 
    l_list = s_line.split()
    list_of_lists = l_list
file1.close()
```

But it didn't work, also it should be case insensitive, can anyone help me please?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask] from the [tour]. "Teach me this basic language feature" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a _specific_ question about your implementation. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: This has a few good tips: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113655/is-there-a-function-in-python-to-split-a-word-into-a-list

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a context manager to open your file, that way you don't risk forgetting to close it:

```
list_of_lists = []
with open('file_input.txt') as file1:
    list_of_lists = [x.lower() for x in file1.read() if x != " " and x != "\n"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to do something like below

```
ans = []
with open("file_input.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        ans.extend(list(line.replace(" ", "")))
print(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `list()` to turn a string into a list of characters, and `str.replace()` to remove any spaces from a string:

```
file = open('file_input.txt', 'r')
result = list(file.read().replace(' ',''))
file.close()
```

Btw, if you also want to remove newlines, just add `.replace('\n', '')` to the end of the result line, before the ')'

Also, if you want to make it case insensitive, just add `.lower()` to the end of the result line, before the ')'